# Let X and Y be continuous random variables with joint density function. Find probability for this function.

Tags: probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be continuous random variables with joint density function

$$ f_{\small X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}xy&:&0\leq x\leq 2, 0\leq y\leq 1 \\[1ex] 0 &:&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Find $$ P(\frac{X}{2}\leq Y\leq X) $$

Comment: is $x$ meant to be $X$?

Comment: Yes... I just edited it...

Answer (score 1):

Drawing out the graph we can see that $x$ goes from $y$ to $2y$ and $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align} \int_0^1\int_y^{2y} xy\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y & = \int_0^1 2y^3-\frac{y^3}{2}\,\mathrm{d}y \\[2ex] &= \left[\frac{y^4}{2}-\frac{y^4}{8}\right]_{y=0}^{y=1} \\[2ex] &= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8} \\[2ex]&= \frac{3}{8}\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm actually going from y to 2y but for some reason the syntax I'm using is not going through. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use ```{...}``` when you are using exponents or subscripts of more than one character. I have fixed that for now, and other minor stuffs.

Comment: thank you so much! initial integral should be xy not just x though... was having trouble with that too in the initial posting as it kept adding an extra y to my equation...

Comment: You did not calculate $P\left(\frac{x}2\leq Y\leq X\right)$ but you calculated $P\left(\frac{X}2\leq Y\leq X\right)$. That is essentially different.

Comment: @drhab it's because I made an error when writing out the problem... it should have said X/2...